# Chevy Cruze small intermittent stutters/misfires/jerks

Tags: chevrolet, acceleration, cruze

My Chevy Cruze 2013 (LT 1.4L engine with automatic transmission) is experiencing jerking/stuttering/misfires (w/e you wanna call them) while lightly accelerating and idle.

Various Details Listed:

- There are no error codes being flagged, so I'm not really sure how to go about troubleshooting this issue.
- I could be imagining it, but it seems like it happens more frequently when the engine is around 1700 RPM. Flooring it has yet to cause any issues and drives perfectly normal.
- Jerks are small and subtle. They started out as only happening once warmed up, but now happen at any time. They started out only happening during light acceleration, but now they happen while idling too (more prominent when idling on an incline/slope).
- There is **NOT** a lack of power aside from the fact the vehicle is doing small little stutters. When they're not happening it's driving perfectly normal.
- Recently replaced Supercharger, lines to the supercharger, spark plugs, and solenoid valve unrelated to this issue.

What are my troubleshooting steps for this?

Comment: Does your Cruze have a standard or automatic transmission?

Comment: Automatic transmission. To clarify it doesn't seem like it's jerking when shifting, just when accelerating in general, so I'd expect it not to be the transmission, but I'm not really an expert.

Comment: I was actually wondering if the clutch was slipping (if manual). The automatic transmission itself could slipping, too. Have you checked the fluid levels in the transmission? (I'm not even sure you can check it in a Cruze.) How many miles on your Cruze?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can or not, but I'll look into it. My cruze has 128K miles on it with a rough history of having to replace every cooling part short of the radiator lol (turbocharger intercooler was dented for a long time without knowing it).

Comment: If you have or could get or borrow a scan tool that can record and graph various parameters while you drive, that might go a long way toward solving the mystery. For example, if you plot RPM and vehicle speed on the same graph and you see RPM momentarily jump while vehicle speed stays the same, that's a good indication of a slipping trans. Or graph throttle % vs manifold pressure for a stretch of time when you are driving at constant speed and load. A jump in manifold pressure when throttle hasn't changed suggests a turbo control issue or an intermittent sensor feeding the turbo software.

Comment: Does it feel like an intermittent misfire? I've had a couple of cars where the ignition coils started failing but didn't generate engine fault codes until the problem worsened

Comment: Very intermittent. I can floor the sucker and have absolutely no problems, but then other times I'll be doing minor to medium acceleration and it starts doing its small little jerks. It feels like a small slip, but today it is icy out and I can definitely tell the difference between the jerks and actually slipping on ice, thought I was going crazy for a bit because they're just so small and subtle.

Comment: @ThaRobster Can it be the ignition coil if I don't have loss of power or anything like that? It's literally just the very small/subtle jerks when accelerating once warm and a ticking noise behind the engine (but the ticking has been there for years at this point I can't remember if it's normal or not lol). It doesn't make noise when it jerks, if anything it's a lack of noise, and the RPM stays mostly the same because it's so brief.

Comment: @Shelby115 Potentially, without being in the car at the time it is difficult to say, however I had similar both in a Mk4 Golf and a R55 Mini, and both started with very subtle things, almost like hesitations. I did find that it happened less with the power full on, but that may just be my experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the ignition coil. Replacing that, it is no longer doing any misfires.